# Apache Redirection two apps wordpress and tomcat

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, tomcat6

I want to configure Wordpress site (http://example.com/blog ) served from Apache. Webapp using Tomcat on same server listens on port 8080. These need to be redirect from 80 to 8080.

I tried reverse proxy method but was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the wordpress configuration:

See table `wp_options`, there are two options:

**1. siteurl**

value: `http://yourhost:port/`

**2. home**

value: `http://yourhost:port/dirname/`

---

When you install the wordpress, the two paths above was set to the database, so if you change the port, it won't change it self, you should change it manually. Or it will always trigger a redirection there.

Comment: I don't see these two options in wp_options table, shows four fields option_id, option_name,option_value and auto load. these are the one your referring?

Comment: @itsramesh `SELECT * FROM wp_options where option_name in ('siteurl', 'home');`

Comment: Yes, I can see two options.i will try to change port,let's hope solves my problem. thanks will update you.

Comment: I've changed siteurl and home as you have suggested.i don't see port 88 listening, please let me know what changes need to make port 88 listen. Thanks.

Comment: @itsramesh that would be a apache configuration, check your apache configuration.

Comment: currently apache listens on port 80, now any request on port 80 redirected to tomcat port 8080, to complete my requirement, I need to install second apache instance and use different port for wordpress?  or any other suggestion? my requirement is http://www.example.com ( tomcat app) , http://www.example.com/blog for wordpress. please suggest me best method to achieve this.

Comment: @itsramesh So you can start another question on it, good luck.